# Visual Studio 2017 updates - affecting compiled code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mfc

We're a team of some C++ MFC developers who recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2017. Quickly noticing that Microsoft is now releasing "Servicing updates" such as version 15.9.10 and 15.9.11 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) we're wondering if it is safe to rund different such minor versions within the team working on the same code? Since we cannot all update Visual Studio at the same time but still need to compile and release code. Will the code be affected by these minor updates to Visual Studio or is it safe to run different minor versions?

Also, in Visual Studio when checking for updates (Help -> Check for updates) it only offers the latest version, or is it somehow possible to choose a version so that we can all stay in sync with a specific version even if Microsoft gets a chance to release subsequent updates between the times that we all have a chance to sync up to a specific version?

Comment: I would not say it is safe. I've seen stuff go from not compiling to compiling on such minor versions changes.  That means someone with a new compiler might be able to write and compile code that you can't.  Why can't you all upgrade to the same version?

Comment: It's difficult to answer that with certainity. AFAIK you cannot download a past version unless you have already saved it with the command line tools. The point is to write code that really does not depend so much on the "unstable" features of the compiler.

Comment: "we cannot all update Visual Studio at the same time" - why not?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, reason is that we work at different companies with different update policies, IT management etc.

Comment: @NeilButterworth See the reply to NathanOliver

Comment: In that case I would try to agree on one version and just stick to that.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, problem is that I ran the web installer and got the 15.9.11 version automatically, while their IT department did not want the web installer and it turned out that their installed version is 15.9.8. But I can't really go back to an older version easily without having to uninstall everything again. Or, we must convince their IT department to allow update to 15.9.11 too.

Comment: Microsoft have invested a lot into binary compatibility (see [C++ Binary Compatibility and Pain-Free Upgrades to Visual Studio 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp-binary-compatibility-and-pain-free-upgrades-to-visual-studio-2019/)). Starting with Visual Studio 2015.3 you can mix any language runtime version with any other version. The language runtime is the important piece, as that's where the virtual abstract machine of the language specification meets the real world.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for the link, very interesting!